# MLE of a discrete random variable

Tags: optimization, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

For some reason I am having difficulty understand how to calculate the mle of a discrete rv.

The pmf is:

$$p(k;\theta) = \left\{\begin{array}{cl}
\dfrac{1-\theta}3&\text{if } k=0\\[5pt]
\dfrac{1}{3}&\text{if } k=1\\[5pt]
\dfrac{1+\theta}{3}&\text{if } k=2\\[5pt]
0&\text{otherwise}&\end{array}\right.$$

We're also told that we have $X_1 , X_2, \ldots , X_n$ iid rvs from the above dist (not told how many $n$)

I need to figure out the likelihood and loglikelihood.

I know that the likelihood is just the product of all the pmfs but i dont get how to do this for this discrete rv.

I also know that the loglikelihood will just end up being the sum of all the logs of the pmfs.. but again.. i am confused. some help would be great!

Comment: The likelihood is "the product of the p.m.f.s" as a function of the parameters, not a function of the observed values. Thus it is misleading simply to call it "the product of the p.m.f.s".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Be aware that, when doing MLE (in general, when doing parametric estimation) you are computing (estimating) a *parameter* of a probability function (pmf). If the variable is discrete, it means (roughly) that its probability function takes discrete values (in this case, $k=1,2,3$), but the parameter itself can be continuous (it can take any real value, in some domain). So, the first thing you need to make clear is that:

- what is the parameter of my pmf that I want to estimate? in this case, it's $\theta$
- it's continuous? what's its domain?  in this case, looking at the pmf, we see that $\theta$ must be in the range $[-1,1]$. In this range, and only in this range the probability function is valid (takes non-negative values). Then the parameter is continous and its domain is $-1 \le\theta \le 1$

Once you have that establlished, you try to write the likelihood. If you are not sure, start by some simple example. Assume you have only two samples, say, $x_1=2$, $x_2=0$. The likelihood of this realization is

$$L(\theta)=p(x_1=2;\theta) \times p(x_2=0;\theta) = \frac{1+\theta}{3} \frac{1-\theta}{3} $$

To write this in general, suppose you have  $n_0$ samples that take value $x=0$, $n_1$ that take value $x=1$ etc. Then

$$L(\theta)=p(x=0;\theta)^{n_0}p(x=1;\theta)^{n_1}p(x=2;\theta)^{n_2}$$

Write that expression down, and take its logarithm if you think this simplifies things (it does). Then ask yourself: for given $n_0,n_1,n_2$, this is a (continous) function of $\theta$,  what is the value of $\theta$ that maximizes
this function, in the given domain?

---

Update: given that you've done your homework, here's my solution
$$\log L(\theta)= n_0 \log(1+\theta) +n_2 \log(1-\theta) +\alpha $$
where $\alpha $ is a term that does not depend on $\theta$ (we can leave it out). This function is differentiable in $(-1,1)$, so we can look for critical points (candidate extrema) as:

$$\frac{d\log L(\theta)}{d \theta}= \frac{n_0}{1+\theta}-\frac{n_2}{1-\theta} $$
Equalling this to zero, we get $\theta_0=(n_0-n_2)/(n_0+n_2)$

Have we already found then the MLE? Not really. We have only found *a critical point* of $L(\theta)$. To assert that a critical point is a global maximum we need to 1) check that it's a local maximum (it could be a local minimum or neither) 2) check that the local maximum is really a global maximum (what about the non-differentiable or boundary points?).

We can usually check that with the second derivative. But in this case it's simpler. We see that at the boundary ($\theta = \pm 1$) the likelihood tends to $-\infty$. Hence, given that the function is differentiable inside the interval, and it has a single critical point, it must be a (local and global) maximum.

Comment: thanks so much! I ended up getting my estimate of theta as $\theta = (n_2-n_0)/(n_0+n_2)$

Comment: Is it possible that it's actually $p(x=0;\theta)=\frac{1+\theta}{3}$ and $p(x=2;\theta)=\frac{1-\theta}{3}$ ? In the updated answer, it is already calculated like that. Because otherwise the critical point of $L(\theta)$ would be a global minimum, and the homework wouldn't make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $1_A$ the indicator function of $A$. That is,

$$1_A(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lcc}0&\text{if}&x\notin A\\1&\text{if}&x\in A\\\end{array}\right.$$

Thus, if $L$ and $\ell$ are the likelihood and loglikelihood, then:

\begin{eqnarray}L(\theta)&=&p(x_1;\theta)\cdots p(x_n;\theta)\\
&=&\prod_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1-\theta}{3}1_{\{0\}}(x_i)+\frac{1}{3}1_{\{1\}}(x_i)+\frac{1+\theta}{3}1_{\{2\}}(x_i)\right)\end{eqnarray}

And

$$\ell(\theta)=\log(L(\theta))=\sum_{i=1}^n\log\left(\frac{1-\theta}{3}1_{\{0\}}(x_i)+\frac{1}{3}1_{\{1\}}(x_i)+\frac{1+\theta}{3}1_{\{2\}}(x_i)\right)$$